# Alpine package py3-scipy is missing

Tags: docker, scipy, alpine-linux

I'm in an alpine linux docker container, and I'm trying to install `py3-scipy`. Here is info on that package: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/py3-scipy. I want to do this because `pip install scipy` takes way too long.

Here is what I get:

```
/ # apk add py3-scipy
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  py3-scipy (missing):
    required by: world[py3-scipy]
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.9
RUN apk add --update python3-dev g++ gcc libxslt-dev cython lapack-dev gfortran build-base py3-scipy
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Please add your complete Dockerfile to the question.  (Installing packages in an interactive shell in a container isn't a best practice; it'll get lost as soon as the container exits.)

Comment: Done (and understood, but I am using an external service that requires a Dockerfile)

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue sometimes happen when alpine moves a package from `edge/testing` to `edge/community` so old versions of alpine will keep referring to the old url. So you need to try to use the latest alpine version `alpine:latest` instead of a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the echo step, with that I was able to install it:

```
echo "@testing http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories
apk add --update --no-cache py3-scipy
```